# Adapter with startActivityForResult

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onactivityresult, startactivityforresult

Good Day everybody i want edit item of Recycle-view startAcivityForResult/onActivityResult my code in BindHolder

```
        holder.title.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent goToOrder= new Intent("Order");
            ((Activity)context).startActivityForResult(goToOrder , 10);
            mDataset.get(position).setType_meat(type_meat);
            mDataset.get(position).setType_rice(type_rice);
        }
    });
```

in BindHolder the value is null but here it work correctly

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 10:
        if (resultCode == -1) {
            type_rice=data.getStringExtra("type_rice");
            type_meat=data.getStringExtra("type_meat");
            Log.e("type rice", type_rice);
            Log.e("type_meat", type_meat);
        }
    }
}
```

Any hint please !
Thanks so much for everybody

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the position of your item  `pos` in the adapter and call

```
  adapter.notifyItemChanged(pos)
```

This will result in calling `onBindViewHolder` for that position.

If it is absolutely impossible to know the position call

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

This will result in `onBindViewHolder` called for every visible item in the adapter

Comment: thanks for replay  ,,, i try you idea but it still null value  i open new Activity when i click on itemTitle the data of object will change depends on result form Activity ,